# Declaration or Statement Expected (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am currently having an issue where I  added a function in my Javascript server that is currently throwing an error.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs')


var server = http.createServer(function (req, res){

    //handle incoming requests here


    if (req.url == '/') {



        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); //sets the headers for the response

        res.write('Welcome to project perfect'); //write an about me page


        res.end();
    }
    else if (req.url == '/spotify' ) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

        fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, data) {  //Figure out why the if logic is making line 39 error
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
```

##The error is being thrown below in the else if statement.

```
    else if (req.url == '/fitness') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

        res.write("Welcome to aroe's fitness page"); //integrate myfitnesspal api and workout recorder

        res.end();
    }

    else if (req.url == '/blog') {

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write('blog');

        res.end();
    }
})
server.listen(8000);

console.log('SERVING ON PORT 8000')
```

The error is saying

```
declaration or statement expected at the this chunk `else if (req.url == '/fitness') {`
```

It only happened after I added the fs.fileread function. Something there is erroring out the next else if logic I present it. I am new to Javascript so I understand this may be trivial. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's no `}` before that `else`

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs')


var server = http.createServer(function (req, res){

    //handle incoming requests here


    if (req.url == '/') {



        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); //sets the headers for the response

        res.write('Welcome to project perfect'); //write an about me page


        res.end();
    }
    else if (req.url == '/spotify' ) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

        fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, data) {  //Figure out why the if logic is making line 39 error
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        })
      } // you're missing this curly brace, it closes the else if above
        else if (req.url == '/fitness') {
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  
          res.write("Welcome to aroe's fitness page"); //integrate myfitnesspal api and workout recorder
  
          res.end();
      }
  
      else if (req.url == '/blog') {
  
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
          res.write('blog');
  
          res.end();
      }
  })
  server.listen(8000);
  
  console.log('SERVING ON PORT 8000')
```

Comment: I had made a mistake, I have corrected my code now, I just added a curly brace to close the first else-if

Answer (score 0):

Missed parenthesis at the end of the if statement containing the fs.fileRead function.